# Looking for a word - sorry - not sorry

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm trying to think of a word or phrase that would mean 'Sorry I was caught, but not sorry for what I did' Unrepentant seems the closest for the second part of it, but doesn't quite convey the first part, too.

Comment: ***Unrepentant*** seems fine to me for your context. But would you like, say, ***unremorseful*** any better?

Comment: @JohnFeltz No. This is not that.

Comment: It's fairly easy to find dozens of written instances of, say, [*remorseful but unrepentant*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22remorseful+but+unrepentant%22). Also [*rueful but not repentant*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rueful+but+not+repentant%22), and [*regretful but unapologetic*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22regretful+but+unapologetic%22), etc.

Comment: I don't think you mean to say that you were *sorry* you were caught at all. Don't you mean to say that you wish you hadn't been caught—or that you were disappointed in yourself for having let yourself be caught? (And, that aside, it seems unlikely there is a word that can describe both things at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

A variant of "unrepentant" is **[impenitent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impenitent)**

> **adjective**
>
> without regret, shame, or remorse; unrepentant

Comment: unrepentant, etc covers the second part, but so far nothing covers the bit about feeling sorry (probably for themself)  about having been caught